# Global audio play state in NextJS (Using .tsx and .jsx)

Tags: next.js, audio, state

Am trying to make an audio player that plays audio globally.
I have the player functions and audio player ui and am calling data from a json file.
but i get errors in the console:

1. app-index.js:35 useAudio() ref to  element is empty at mount. It seem you have not rendered the audio element, which it returns as the first argument const [audio] = useAudio(...).
2. Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
3. SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON
4. Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h466T.png)

I prepared the json file with song info

```json
 [
   {
     "id": 1,
     "artist": "Luxono ft map yamz, slaksum",
     "title": "my honey",
     "cover": "https://cdn.zambianplay.com/wp-content/uploads/2024/02/Luxono-Ft.-Maps-Wamz-My-Honey.jpg",
     "url": "/data/Luxono-My-Honey.mp3"
   },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "artist": "Taylor Swift",
    "title": "Blank Space",
    "cover": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/5/5a/Taylor_Swift_-_Blank_Space.png",
    "url": "https://www.soundhelix.com/examples/mp3/SoundHelix-Song-2.mp3"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "artist": "Bruno Mars",
    "title": "That's What I Like",
    "cover": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/1/17/Bruno_Mars_-_That%27s_What_I_Like.png",
    "url": "https://www.soundhelix.com/examples/mp3/SoundHelix-Song-3.mp3"
  }
]
```

I wrote the audioplayer functions

```js
"use client"
// This is a custom hook that creates a global state for the audio player
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useAudio } from "react-use";
import playlist from "../../../public/data/_playlist.json";
export const  useGlobalAudioPlayer = () => {
    const defaultTrack = playlist[0];
    // This is the global state that stores the current track, playlist, and playback status
    const [state, setState] = useState({
        track: defaultTrack, // Set default track here
        playlist: playlist,
        playing: false,
        repeat: false,
        shuffle: false,
    });

    // This is the audio element that plays the track
    const [audio, stateAudio, controlsAudio, refAudio] = useAudio({
        src: state.track?.url,
        autoPlay: false,
        loop: state.repeat,
    });

    // This is a helper function that shuffles an array
    const shuffleArray = (array) => {
        let currentIndex = array.length,
            randomIndex;

        // While there remain elements to shuffle...
        while (currentIndex !== 0) {
            // Pick a remaining element...
            randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
            currentIndex--;

            // And swap it with the current element.
            [array[currentIndex], array[randomIndex]] = [
                array[randomIndex],
                array[currentIndex],
            ];
        }

        return array;
    };

    // This is a helper function that plays the next track in the playlist
    const playNext = () => {
        if (state.playlist.length > 0) {
            let nextIndex = state.playlist.indexOf(state.track) + 1;
            if (nextIndex >= state.playlist.length) {
                nextIndex = 0;
            }
            setState({ ...state, track: state.playlist[nextIndex] });
        }
    };

    // This is a helper function that plays the previous track in the playlist
    const playPrevious = () => {
        if (state.playlist.length > 0) {
            let prevIndex = state.playlist.indexOf(state.track) - 1;
            if (prevIndex < 0) {
                prevIndex = state.playlist.length - 1;
            }
            setState({ ...state, track: state.playlist[prevIndex] });
        }
    };

    // This is a helper function that toggles the repeat mode
    const toggleRepeat = () => {
        setState({ ...state, repeat: !state.repeat });
    };

    // This is a helper function that toggles the shuffle mode
    const toggleShuffle = () => {
        if (state.shuffle) {
            // If shuffle is on, restore the original playlist order
            setState({
                ...state,
                shuffle: false,
                playlist: state.playlist.sort((a, b) => a.id - b.id),
            });
        } else {
            // If shuffle is off, randomize the playlist order
            setState({
                ...state,
                shuffle: true,
                playlist: shuffleArray([...state.playlist]),
            });
        }
    };

    // This is a helper function that formats the time in seconds to mm:ss format
    const formatTime = (time) => {
        const minutes = Math.floor(time / 60);
        const seconds = Math.floor(time % 60);
        return `${minutes.toString().padStart(2, "0")}:${seconds
            .toString()
            .padStart(2, "0")}`;
    };


    // This is an effect that fetches the audio files and cover from a JSON file and sets the playlist
    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchPlaylist = async () => {
            try {
                const response = await fetch(playlist);
                const data = await response.json();
                setState({ ...state, playlist: data });
            } catch (error) {
                console.error(error);
            }
        };
        fetchPlaylist();
    }, []);

    // This is an effect that updates the playing status when the track changes
    useEffect(() => {
        if (state.track) {
            setState({ ...state, playing: true });
        } else {
            setState({ ...state, playing: false });
        }
    }, [state.track]);

    // This is an effect that listens to the audio events and triggers the next track when the current track ends
    useEffect(() => {
        if (refAudio.current) {
            refAudio.current.addEventListener("ended", playNext);
            return () => {
                refAudio.current.removeEventListener("ended", playNext);
            };
        }
    }, [refAudio, state.playlist]);

    // This is the global context that exposes the state and actions to the components
    return {
        state,
        audio,
        stateAudio,
        controlsAudio,
        playNext,
        playPrevious,
        toggleRepeat,
        toggleShuffle,
        formatTime,
    }
}
```

then i called the functions into the player ui

```js
"use client"
// This is a component that renders the audio player UI
import { useGlobalAudioPlayer } from "./globalplayer";
import {FaBackwardStep, FaForwardStep, FaRepeat, FaShuffle, FaVolumeHigh} from "react-icons/fa6";
import {FaPauseCircle, FaPlayCircle} from "react-icons/fa";


export const AudioPlayer = () => {
    // This is the global context that provides the state and actions for the audio player
    const {
        state,
        audio,
        stateAudio,
        controlsAudio,
        playNext,
        playPrevious,
        toggleRepeat,
        toggleShuffle,
        formatTime,
    } = useGlobalAudioPlayer();

    // This is a helper function that renders the track title and artist
    const renderTrackInfo = () => {
        if (state.track) {
            return (
                <div className="cover-title inline-flex gap-x-1">
                    <div className="cover">
                     <img src={state.track.cover} alt={state.track.title} className="song-cover"/>
                    </div>
                    <div className="title">
                        <h3>{state.track.title}</h3>
                        <h5>{state.track.artist}</h5>
                    </div>

                </div>
            );
        } else {
            return <div className="no-tract">No track selected</div>;
        }
    };

    // This is a helper function that renders the playback controls
    const renderControls = () => {
        return (
            <div className="controls inline-flex items-center gap-x-1">
                <button
                    className="icon-button"
                    onClick={playPrevious}
                    title="Previous"
                >
                    <FaBackwardStep/>
                </button>
                <button
                    className="icon-button"
                    onClick={state.playing ? controlsAudio.pause : controlsAudio.play}
                    title={state.playing ? "Pause" : "Play"}
                >
                    {state.playing ? (<FaPauseCircle/>) : (<FaPlayCircle/>) }
                </button>
                <button
                    className="icon-button"
                    onClick={playNext}
                    title="Next"
                >
                    <FaForwardStep/>
                </button>
                <button
                    className="icon-button"
                    onClick={toggleRepeat}
                    title="Repeat"
                >
                    <FaRepeat
                        className={`repeat ${
                            state.repeat ? "active" : "inactive"
                        }`}
                    />
                </button>
                <button
                    className="icon-button"
                    onClick={toggleShuffle}
                    title="Shuffle"
                >
                    <FaShuffle
                        className={`shuffle ${
                            state.shuffle ? "active" : "inactive"
                        }`}
                    />
                </button>
            </div>
        );
    };

    // This is a helper function that renders the volume control
    const renderVolume = () => {
        return (
            <div className="volume">
                <FaVolumeHigh/>
                <input
                    type="range"
                    min="0"
                    max="1"
                    step="0.01"
                    value={stateAudio.volume}
                    onChange={(e) => controlsAudio.volume(Number(e.target.value))}
                    className="volume-range"
                />
            </div>
        );
    };

    // This is a helper function that renders the progress bar and time
    const renderProgress = () => {
        return (
            <div className="progress-time flex items-center justify-space gap-x-1">
                <span>
                    {formatTime(stateAudio.time || 0)}
                </span>
                <input
                    type="range"
                    min="0"
                    max={stateAudio.duration || 0}
                    value={stateAudio.time || 0}
                    onChange={(e) => controlsAudio.seek(Number(e.target.value))}
                    className="progress-holder"
                />
                <span className="text-primary">
                    {formatTime((stateAudio.duration || 0) - (stateAudio.time || 0))}
                </span>
            </div>
        );
    };

    // This is the main render function that returns the audio player component
    return (
        <div className="player">
            <div className="player-holder flex items-center justify-space">
                {audio}
                {renderTrackInfo()}
                {renderControls()}
                {renderProgress()}
                {renderVolume()}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};
```

Then I called the rendered controls from the audio player ui which plays and pauses audio into the card that contains the songs.

```js
// This is a corrected code snippet for a Next.js audio player component
"use client";
import React from "react";
import { useGlobalAudioPlayer } from "@/components/player/globalplayer";
import { FaPauseCircle, FaPlayCircle } from "react-icons/fa";

import playlist from "../../../public/data/_playlist.json";


const Singles = () => {

    const {
        state,
        controlsAudio,
    } = useGlobalAudioPlayer();

    // This is a helper function that renders the playback controls
    const renderControls = () => {
        return (
            <button
                className="icon-button"
                onClick={state.playing ? controlsAudio.pause : controlsAudio.play}
                title={state.playing ? "Pause" : "Play"}
            >
                {state.playing ? (<FaPauseCircle className="text-primary"/>) : (<FaPlayCircle className="text-primary"/>) }
            </button>
        );
    };

    return (
        <div className="recent-singles p-t-4rem p-b-4rem">
            <div className="wrapper">
                <div className="heading text-left">
                    <h2>New releases</h2>
                </div>
                <div className="grid repeat-row-6 gap-x-1 p-t-2rem p-b-2rem">
                    {playlist.map((track) => (
                        <div className="single-card" key={track.id}>
                            <div className="single-card-cover">
                                <div className="status">
                                    <>
                                        {renderControls}
                                    </>
                                </div>

                                <img
                                    src={track.cover}
                                    alt={track.title}
                                />
                            </div>
                            <div className="single-card-details">
                                <h4 className="text-cap fb">{track.title}</h4>
                                <h5 className="text-cap text-primary">{track.artist}</h5>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    ))}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
export default Singles;
```

And i expect the code to work but its not. only showing the cover, title, duration, the player is able to skip when the song cover and title shows and the volume control is moving but the audio is not playing.
I suspect something wrong with `useAudio` from react-use when mounting the audio url.